# String alignment without monospaced font

Tags: c#, excel, string, vsto

I want an aligned string across multiple rows in a right-click menu in excel. The right click menu is added like this:

```
 CommandBar contextMenu = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["List Range Popup"];
 CommandBarPopup subMenu = (CommandBarPopup)contextMenu.Controls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before: 1, Temporary: true);
 subMenu.Caption = "Assumptions Drill Down";
```

I then iterate database results and add to the subMenu in the proceeding rows 
Current result as below (using string padding):[image]

As the character spaces are not even (non-monospaced font) the columns are not aligned. I've tried to do something like the below to get the pixel size of the string and then covert back to the required string padding integer but I cant get it to work:

```
    private static double GetStringSize(string stringText)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(stringText,
            new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point));
        return size.Width;
    }
```

1. Is there a way to set font on a right click to monospaced (i dont believe so)
2. If I cant do (1.) how can I make sure spacing in each column is even - so for example evenly align a user of 'iiiii' vs 'QQQQQ'
   ?